# Getting wrong locale for Portuguese (Brazil)

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am trying to get system locale for Portuguese (Brazil), but it is giving the decimal separator as `.` instead of `,` Can anyone please help on that? I am using Java 8.

Below is the code I am using:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final Locale locale = new Locale(System.getProperty("user.country.format"));
    
    final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
     
    DecimalFormatSymbols decSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
    System.out.println("Decimal Symbol"+ decSymbols.getDecimalSeparator() + "");
}
```

Getting decimal separator as `.` instead of `,`.

Comment: First question: What is the value of `System.getProperty("user.country.format")` ?

Comment: value of System.getProperty("user.country.format") is "br"

Comment: Why is this tagged `bigdecimal`?

Comment: BTW the first parameter of the `Locale` constructor is the language ('pt'), not the country ('BR'); BTW-2 the constructors of `Locale` are *now* deprecated since Java 19

Comment: ... and [_language_ 'br' is Breton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes#br) (@user85421)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get your expected decimal separator `,` using the `pt` locale (Portugal):

```
final Locale locale = new Locale("pt");
final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
DecimalFormatSymbols decSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
System.out.println("Decimal Symbol"+ decSymbols.getDecimalSeparator() + "");
```

I did not see any `br` locale returned from a call to `DateFormat.getAvailableLocales()`, so either it doesn't exist at all (at least in my JRE) or it is using decimal point as the decimal separator.  Note that the `pt_BR` locale is what I think you should be using, but that assumes that your JRE supports it.  If not, then maybe your code would just use the default locale.

Comment: For "pt" we are getting the correct decimal seperator i.e. ','
We are getting the 'pt_br' from a call to DateFormat.getAvailableLocales(), so either 'pt_br' or 'br' both are returning '.' as decimal seperator instead of returning ',' as decimal seperator, while in system setting we are getting decimal seperator as ','

Comment: @ashishsharma You don't seem Brazilian to me.  Are you certain that the custom in Brazil in fact is to use comma as the decimal separator?

Comment: Yes , I am sure because I encountered an issue where the user reported the same

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Brazil and the rest of South-America (with one exception, AFAICT) use the comma as decimal separator.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Perhaps the OP's JRE does not support `pt_BR`.

Comment: I'm Brazilian. We use `,` as _decimal separator_ and `.` as _thousand separator_.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen ...so this can be the jre issue ?

Comment: What other explanation comes to mind?  The Brazilian locale should behave as you expect.

Comment: @ashishsharma: not necessarily a JRE issue. More a platform issue, i.e. the OS on which the JRE runs may not have all locales installed.